# Hibernate join tables duplicate entry - Could not execute JDBC batch update

Tags: hibernate, join, duplicates

I have a simple domain class Licensee:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "LICENSEE")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
public class Licensee implements Serializable, Comparable {
    private Integer id;
    private String orgName;

    /* ... */

    private Set<Address> address = new HashSet<Address>();

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "increment")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "increment", strategy = "org.hibernate.id.IncrementGenerator")
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column(name = "ORGNAME")
    public String getOrgName() {
        return orgName;
    }

    public void setOrgName(String orgName) {
        this.orgName = orgName;
    }

    /* ... */

    @OneToMany
    @Cascade({org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.ALL, org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.DELETE_ORPHAN})
    @JoinTable(name = "LICENSEEADDRESS",
        joinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "LICENSEEID", unique = true)
        },
        inverseJoinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "ADDRESSID")
        }
    )
    public Set<Address> getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(Set<Address> address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public void addAddress(Address address) {
        this.address.add(address);
    }
}
```

which holds a reference to a Set of Address objects. I'm using the @JoinTable annotation for the db relation between the two classes. I have hibernate.hbm2ddl set to create which creates the join table LICENSEEADDRESS with a composite key consisting of the LICENSEEID and the ADDRESSID as expected. However, when I call saveOrUpdate on a Licensee object with more than one Address object in the Set at a time, I get this:

```
java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Duplicate entry '1' for key 2
com.mysql.jdbc.ServerPreparedStatement.executeBatch(ServerPreparedStatement.java:647)
org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingStatement.executeBatch(DelegatingStatement.java:297)
org.hibernate.jdbc.BatchingBatcher.doExecuteBatch(BatchingBatcher.java:70)
org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:268)
org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:266)
org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:171)
org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:321)
org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:50)
org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1027)
org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:365)
org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.commit(JDBCTransaction.java:137)
org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager.doCommit(HibernateTransactionManager.java:655)
org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:732)
org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:701)
org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:321)
org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:116)
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:89)
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
$Proxy18.saveLicensee(Unknown Source)
net.grouplink.gilf.web.controllers.LicenseeFormController.onSubmit(LicenseeFormController.java:64)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleFormController.processFormSubmission(SimpleFormController.java:267)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractFormController.handleRequestInternal(AbstractFormController.java:265)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:153)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:48)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:875)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:807)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:571)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:511)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:710)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
```

So the second query in the batch isn't completed because it thinks there is a duplicate key, which is true for that one column. But with a composite key, wouldn't both ids need to be the same to cause a constraint violation? What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Took out "unique = true" and it's working.

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/bleonard/archive/2006/11/using_composite.html) outlines how to set up a composite key using an arbitrary JPA provider.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Your answer made me take a closer look at my annotations. Somehow I let unique=true slip in there, which was causing it. Thanks for the link though.